# How to check a checkbox in excel file using epplus in vb.net

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, web, epplus

I am using epplus for reading an existing excel file which contains a checkbox in cell `C23`.

I would like to know how I can check this cell `C23` in vb.net :

```
Using file As FileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath)
Using package as ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(file)
Dim book As ExcelWorkbook = package.Workbook
Dim sheet As ExcelWorksheet = book.Worksheets.First()
sheet.Cells("C23").Value = checked..... //I dont know how to check the checkbox
```

I've also tried Googling it but haven't found anything in the right direction yet.

Comment: EPPlus does not support form controls. You can however use unicode checkmarks "☑" "☐"

Comment: @Jeff is correct.  As of June 2020, EPPlus does not support form controls.  See this [FAQ](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/FAQ) for general list of what is and is not supported.